# How to retrieve component by specific Schema?

Tags: 2013, templating, content-manager, razormediator

I have a schema id. based on that schema id i want to retrieve all components modified date (created by that schema).

How to resolve it?

Comment: Is there a reason that they are not already on the Page as Component Presentation's? Normally, if you want to render a Component at publish time you would have it as a Component Presentation on the Page already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all Components based on a Schema and from a particular Publication?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-get-all-components-based-on-a-schema-and-from-a-particular-publication)

Comment: no components are not added in component presentation directly...in component presentation i have added one component,in that component i have given one schema tcm id, based on that tcm id i have to retrieve components..

Comment: As tagged ([tag:templating]) this question is not a duplicate of http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2320/46. This question can be improved, though. Sudip, please include what you've tried and maybe what you're expecting. You've provided background that this is a templating question for Razor Mediator, which is a good start. But the community will not generally write code for you; rather they can guide you and clarify parts you don't understand, especially if you've researched and given it some effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of components wich uses that schema by this TOM.NET code:

```
UsingItemsFilter filter = new UsingItemsFilter(schema.Session);
filter.ItemTypes = new List<ItemType> { ItemType.Component };
filter.IncludedVersions = VersionCondition.OnlyLatestVersions;

IEnumerable<IdentifiableObject> components = schema.GetUsingItems(filter);
```

Then, for each component of the returned list you can retrieve the propertiy "RevisionDate".

Also you cas use Tridion CoreService to obtain the list of components based on that schema:

```
SearchQueryData query = new SearchQueryData() {
    BasedOnSchemas = new BasedOnSchemaData[] { 
        new BasedOnSchemaData(){ 
            Schema = new LinkToSchemaData(){ IdRef= "{schemaId}" }
        }
    },
    SearchIn = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData() { IdRef = "{publicationId}" }, 
    ItemTypes = new ItemType[]{ ItemType.Component }
};

XElement xResults = channel.GetSearchResultsXml(query);
```

This is from this post:
[How to get all Components based on a Schema and from a particular Publication?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-get-all-components-based-on-a-schema-and-from-a-particular-publication)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Julian. Thanks for helping out here by copying the answer. What we generally prefer, though, is to flag the question as a duplicate. This gives people a better chance of finding high-quality answers on the site.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I flag it.

Comment: whether the "schema" filed in above expression will bethe name of the schema or TCM id of the schema?

Comment: In the first sample is a schema object:                                                Schema schema = (Schema)_Engine.GetObject(YourSchemaUri);

Comment: I am not geeting the components by 1st code..pls help me out

Comment: Actually i am printing one by one....Schema value i am getting "tcm:8-408-8"..then 1st "filter" value i am getting <p>Tridion.ContentManager.UsingItemsFilter</p>

Comment: Below Code i have written:below coding..Schema schema = (Schema)TridionHelper.Engine.GetObject(TridionHelper.Package.GetValue("tcm:8-408-8"));
<p>@schema</p>
<p>@schema.Session</p>
UsingItemsFilter filter = new UsingItemsFilter(schema.Session);
<p>@filter</p>
filter.ItemTypes = new List<ItemType> { ItemType.Component };
filter.IncludedVersions =VersionCondition.OnlyLatestVersions;<p>@filter</p>IEnumerable<IdentifiableObject> components = schema.GetUsingItems(filter);
                           <p>@components</p>

Comment: the first code works for me, you get some error? Else you can try use coreservice and SearchQueryData. Have you read the post I indicated?

Comment: For the first aproach also try this way:                                            TcmUri uri = new TcmUri("tcm:8-408‌​-8");
UsingItemsFilter filter = new UsingItemsFilter(engine.GetSession()) { ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component } };
Schema schema = (Schema)engine.GetObject(uri);

 foreach (Component c in schema.GetUsingItems(filter))
            {
       
       //..."Here your code"
   
     }

Comment: One thing do you know how to get current page URL in razor or TOM .Net ?

Comment: In TOM.NET: Page.PublishLocationUrl

Comment: above code will give me the Tridion Page URL but I want current page URL whatever is there in the browser.Actually I am implementing this functionality for dynamic page.I have one page and 100 components. That 100 components dynamically indexed to that one page and reform 100 page URL.