# Component's schema missing values using CoreService

Tags: core-service, schema, component

I'm using CoreService to get a list of Components using Schema like described [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12274/how-to-retrieve-component-by-specific-schema). My problem is that I can't get the values of the Schema fields used in each Component. The list shows property Schema but I can't see the values set in the Component that uses that Schema. The Schema has two fields whose values are set per Component.

I need those How can I get them?

Here is the information retrieved

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your screenshot, notice how the "Content" attribute is null. For each component, you need to call:

```
ComponentData component = (ComponentData)coreServiceClient.Read(
                                  componentTcmId, new ReadOptions());
```

Now you can parse the **component.Content** to read the field values.

By the way, if you happen to have metadata fields as well, you will need to parse the **component.Metadata** to read the metadata field values.