# SearchQueryData returns top 1000 reults

Tags: core-service, schema, component

I am trying to get a list of all components based on a schema which are like 2000+ via core service. when using code from [How to get all Components based on a Schema and from a particular Publication?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-get-all-components-based-on-a-schema-and-from-a-particular-publication) its returns only top 1000. Any other way to get all the components. I know there will be timeouts and it will be heavy, but this is a one time run application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your query uses the underlying Tridion search functionality, it is processed using the standard Solr request handler.

In the [Tridion Home]\solr-home\tridion\conf\solrconfig.xml file, this request handler is set to return a maximum of 1000 rows:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="defType">complex</str>
      <int name="rows">1000</int>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

If you expect your CME queries to need to return more than 1000 results, this `rows` setting can be increased.

You may need to restart Solr's application server, or run the Reload command to get changes to take effect.

Comment: Excellent. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use Search for this. A where used query will also work, and might be the better choice. Here's a powershell snippet to illustrate how you might do this:

```
$core = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
$filter = new-object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.UsingItemsFilterData
$filter.ItemTypes = "Component"
$components = $core.GetList("tcm:28-587-8", $filter) | %{$core.Read($_.Id,$null)}
```

Comment: I agree with Dominic that the where used query is a better option here - as it doesn't rely on the Solr search indexes being up to date.

Comment: Makes sense Dominic, will change my code accordingly.. thank you