# UsingItemsFilter not filtering result for publication context

Tags: web8, templating, tom.net

In my c# tbb, I am trying to fetch all the components using the particular keyword in a publication context. The code which I am using is:

```
UsingItemsFilter filter = new UsingItemsFilter(pub.Session)
{
   ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component },
   IncludedVersions = VersionCondition.OnlyLatestVersions
};
var classifiedComponents = keyword.GetListUsingItems(filter);
```

It's filtering all the components which is associated with the particular keyword (suppose i am picking any keyword from the lowest child publication). I assumed, it should be filtered only those components which are in publication hierarchy.

But not, its fetching all components which are also not in publication hierarchy.

Can anyone please suggest, how can i get only those components which are only associated from the publication hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to be interested in classified Components: did you consider using `Keyword.GetClassifiedItems` ?

Comment: Thanks Rick. Still I haven't used this method, but I am sure it will also not work. Reason for this assumption is, the extra components which I can see is also classified with that item but those components are not in the context blueprint hierarchy.

Comment: Try using that method. I think it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Yeah, this method is returning only components which are classified in context to publication blueprint.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `InRepository`.

```
UsingItemsFilter = new UsingItemsFilter(pub.Session)
{
   ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component },
   IncludedVersions = VersionCondition.OnlyLatestVersions,
   InRepository = new LinkToRepositoryData(){IdRef="tcm:0-{PUB-ID}-0"}
};
var classifiedComponents = keyword.GetListUsingItems(filter);
```

I don't have the documentation available but I'm sure I recall that there could be some challenge with localised or shared content so I'd certainly test for local, shared and localised Components (in which case - maybe `IncludeLocalCopies` = true can be used?).

### UPDATE

Actually I just checked something and recalled a similar question when I had problems. 
There's a full explanation [here from Bart](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-get-all-components-based-on-a-schema-and-from-a-particular-publication/2331#2331).

but essentially you have

- Drop the `InRepository`
- Filter out duplicate item IDs
- Filter out items from the child Publications
- Replace the Publication IDs of parent Publications in your context Publication

Or, as you'll see in the post noted above, you could use `SearchQueryData` but you're relying on the setup of search etc.

Comment: @Mark, I have already tried InRepository with slightly changed syntax as I am using Tom.Net api(syntax: filter.InRepository=currentPublication). But it is only returning items created or localized in that publication. I have also tried IncludeLocalCopies, but it was also not returning the desired result.

Comment: Can you eloborate on _not returning the desired results_ ... you state above that the issue is you current receive items "which are also not in publication hierarchy." -> but this solution returns Local and localised items so I would have expected that IncludeLocalCopies would complete the circle and return inherited items - *but not* those outside the blueprint?

Comment: @Mark, using IncludeLocalCopies in addition to the code mentioned in the question was also not returning all the component of context publication blueprint.

Comment: Well I suspect that's the nearest you'll get. You can skip through the response and just remove anything that has "isShared" :)